# When are primaries not orthogonal in CFTs?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

I know from conformal symmetry that if two quasi-primaries have different dimensions, they will be orthogonal. Is there an example of a theory where two quasi-primaries which necessarily have the same dimension are NOT orthogonal?

For example, N free bosons have the same dimension but will have vanishing two point function for bosons of different flavors.

Answer (score 3):

If operators have the same dimension, then by following the Gram-Schmidt process, we can construct a basis where the operators are orthogonal. Inversely, yes - in general, there can be operators with the same dimension that are not orthogonal.

As a simple example, if $O_1$ and $O_2$ are orthogonal operators with dimension $\Delta$  so that
$$
\langle O_i(1) O_j(0) \rangle = \delta_{ij}
$$
Define $O_3 = O_1 + O_2$. Then, $O_3$ also has dimension $\Delta$ and now
$$
\langle O_1(1) O_3(0) \rangle = 1 \neq 0~. 
$$